# Fotos e anexos personalizados no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou precisando colocar galeria de fotos e arquivos anexos nos posts e páginas do Wordpress, porém com um estilo personalizado na exibição dentro do post.

Como faço pra apenas subir as imagens e arquivos na edição, vinculado-os com o *post*, e depois na *view* consultar para exibi-los?

Quero vincular as imagens/arquivos no *post* para poder mostrar quando visualizar o *post*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use um plugin de anexos

Para vincular arquivos ao post você pode usar um plugin como [este](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/). Não usei este plugin e existem outros, então pesquise bem e escolha um deles.

Esses plugins de anexos vão adicionar campos na edição de postagens e páginas para você associar arquivos.

## Exibindo os anexos

Cada plugin também vai ter uma forma de você incluir os arquivos na visualização de postagens e páginas.

Alguns plugins disponibilizam *shortcodes*, que é um pequeno texto que você coloca dentro do conteúdo do artigo e o plugin adiciona automaticamente o conteúdo.

Outra forma é usando código diretamente nas telas. O plugin citado acima dá o seguinte exemplo:

```php
<?php $attachments = new Attachments( 'attachments' ); /* pass the instance name */ ?>
<?php if( $attachments->exist() ) : ?>
  <h3>Attachments</h3>
  <p>Total Attachments: <?php echo $attachments->total(); ?></p>
  <ul>
    <?php while( $attachments->get() ) : ?>
      <li>
        ID: <?php echo $attachments->id(); ?><br />
        Type: <?php echo $attachments->type(); ?><br />
        Subtype: <?php echo $attachments->subtype(); ?><br />
        URL: <?php echo $attachments->url(); ?><br />
        Image: <?php echo $attachments->image( 'thumbnail' ); ?><br />
        Source: <?php echo $attachments->src( 'full' ); ?><br />
        Size: <?php echo $attachments->filesize(); ?><br />
        Title Field: <?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?><br />
        Caption Field: <?php echo $attachments->field( 'caption' ); ?>
      </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

## Exibindo imagens

Possivelmente é possível usar o mesmo plugin de anexos para exibir as imagens. Basta filtrar os arquivos que são imagens e exibir usando a tag `<img>`.

Se quiser outra alternativa, pesquise por algum outro plugin especificamente de galeria de imagens. Há vários por lá que permitem criar galerias e mostrar com *shortcodes* ou código personalizado.